# The number of undirected graphs reprezentate în the same matrix

Tags: c++, c

I have in the same adiacence matrix for many undirected graphs. I need a idea to find the number of graphs from the matrix.
I have to dolce this in c/c++.

Comment: Many of us old guys dislike the term "C/C++" quite a lot. There's no such language as "C/C++", there is either the language C or the *very* different language C++. A solution to even a simple problem can differ quite a lot depending on the language selected. So please pick *one* language.

Comment: Also please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: If I understand well your need, you should have selected the tag "algorithm" only, not "C" or "C++". This tag corresponds to the correct answer provided

Comment: Please give an example of two _different_ graphs having the _same_ adjacency matrix.

Answer (score 1):

> I have in the same adjacency matrix many undirected graphs. I need an idea to find the number of graphs from the matrix.

This means that you have many unconnected components in the matrix (i.e. graphs that do not connect to each other).

- take a random node and follow its edges, marking each node visited. If you cannot continue, you have found one component.
- take a random node that has not yet been visited and do the same.
- repeat until all nodes are marked.

For the marking, take an integer that you increment with each component marked. That allows you to identify (and list) the components and at the same time tell how many components there are.